# How does std::notify_all_at_thread_exit work?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, standards, language-implementation

According to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/notify_all_at_thread_exit):

> `std::notify_all_at_thread_exit` provides a mechanism to notify other
>   threads that a given thread has completely finished, including
>   destroying all thread_local objects.

I know the exact semantics of `std::notify_all_at_thread_exit`. What makes me puzzled is:

**How to register a callback function that will be called after a given thread has finished and destroyed all of its thread-local objects?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::notify_all_at_thread_exit` takes a condition variable in its first parameter, by reference. When the thread exits, it will call `notify_all` on that condition variable, waking up threads that are waiting for the condition variable to be notified.

There doesn't appear to be a direct way to truly register a callback for this; you'll likely need to have a thread waiting for the condition variable to be notified (using the same lock as the one passed into `std::notify_all_at_thread_exit`. When the CV is notified, the thread that's waiting should verify that the wakeup isn't spurious, and then execute the desired code that should be run.

More info about how this is implemented:
At least on [Google's libcxx](https://github.com/google/libcxx/blob/master/src/condition_variable.cpp#L76), [`std::notify_all_at_thread_exit`](https://github.com/google/libcxx/blob/master/src/condition_variable.cpp#L76) calls [`__thread_struct_imp::notify_all_at_thread_exit`](https://github.com/google/libcxx/blob/27c836ff3a9c505deb9fd1616012924de8ff9279/src/thread.cpp#L168), which stores a pair with the parameters to a vector (`_Notify`). Upon thread death, the [destructor](https://github.com/google/libcxx/blob/27c836ff3a9c505deb9fd1616012924de8ff9279/src/thread.cpp#L151) of `__thread_struct_imp` iterates over this vector and notifies all of the condition variables that have been registered in this way.

Meanwhile, GNU stdc++ uses a similar approach: A `notifier` object is created, it's registered with `__at_thread_exit`, it's designed to call its destructor when run at thread exit, and the destructor actually performs the notification process. I'd need to investigate `__at_thread_exit` more closely as I don't understand its inner workings fully just yet.

Comment: How to guarantee that `notify_all` will be called after all the thread-local objects has be destroyed? How to implement that under Linux/Windows?

Comment: @xmllmx I've added an overview of how one standard library implementation achieves this to the post.